# bash redirect stdout and stderr to separate commands over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, stdout, stderr

I am using BASH 4.  I am trying to find a way to legitimately prepend output to indicate the type of output that it is.  I am able to do this with something kind of like this...

```
ls -l /tmp/abcdefgh 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
stderr: ls: cannot access /tmp/abcdefgh: No such file or directory

ls -l /tmp/ 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
stdout: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-10-15 09:08 fsck
stdout: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2010-09-10 06:01 kernel
stdout: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2010-09-10 06:01 temp_keys
...
```

This seems to do the trick when I am logged in via SSH and run it interactively.  However, this does not always work right if I try to just run the command as a remote command via ssh with the command in quotes.  I can always get the stdout lines, but sometimes not the stderr lines.

This will produce output...

```
ssh root@server1 "ls -l /tmp/ 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')"
```

This will not produce even an error message...

```
ssh root@server1 "ls -l /tmp/abcdefgh 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')"
```

However, this shows the wget status results as stderr results (which it should)

```
ssh root@server1 "wget http://server2/package.rpm 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')"
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this (in other words, it works for me). Does your example fail? My guess is that the problem is with some complex quoting required by your real command.

Comment: Oddly enough the "ls -l /tmp/abcdefgh" is the real command that produced the problem...  or I should say did not produce an error.  In fact, anytime I pass ls with a file that does not exist, it just gives me nothing.  The specific BASH version is 4.1.2.  Again, if I ssh in and run the command, no problem.  If I pass the command like the above, it reports nothing.  Other commands appear fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following on my computer, with no ssh involved at all:

```
$ ls asdfasdf 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
$ stderr: ls: cannot access asdfasdf: No such file or directory
```

That $ in the second line isn't a typo.  Those sed commands are being run entirely in the background.  `ls` gave its error message and finished with enough time for the shell to output the prompt before sed got a chance to output anything.  I think the far side of your ssh is closing the connection before sed's output arrives.

Buffering through a subshell and a pipe might work better, because `cat` waits for its input to close rather than waiting for the foreground process to finish:

```
ssh root@server1 "(ls -l /tmp/abcdefgh 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')) | cat"
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try that and post results back later today.